# Why does my desktop picture not change correctly?

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control

If I go into the Desktop & Screensaver preference pane to change my desktop background.

The result is that my normal desktop has the old picture I wanted to change:

[image: Desktop]

If, however, I go into Mission Control to change to another virtual desktop, both thumbnails show the correct wallpaper.

[image: Mission Control]

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: Have you attempted to log out of the account and log back in?

Comment: I have. I does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open **Finder** and press the keyboard combination: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- From the "Go To Folder" popup window that appears, enter the following bolded path (just copy and paste it):

**~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db**

- Move the file to your Trash.
- Log out of the account and log back in.

**Explanation:**
There's no property list for Desktop settings in Mavericks, as there was in previous OSXs. Instead, the Desktop values are stored in the database file mentioned above, which I assumed (correctly, here) was corrupted. Deleting it is non-destructive, as it automatically regenerates once you log out and log back in.

Comment: A little explanation of what you're suggesting to do, what that file is and what might have caused the issue would improve your answer :)

Comment: @Thecafremo sure. see edits. cheers :)